# Opening Document's using Document ID (DocIdRedir.aspx) results in Read-Only mode

Tags: document-id, office

SharePoint 2010 has a nice feature called "Document ID".
This gives users the ability to open documents using `[siteurl]/_layouts/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=[DOCIDHERE]`

This works fine, but It always opens the documents in read-only mode.
Normally when a word document is opened in read-only, you have a button on top saying "edit document". But using the `docidredir.aspx` page, this button is not visible in word.

Anyone know how to edit a document this way?

Thanks

Comment: I am having the same issue. Have you figured this out?

Comment: Hi, I have not realy verified the solution, but it might have something todo with the browsers safe zones (u can add sites to a trusted site)...

Comment: I have tested this solution and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Which solution are you talking about ?

Answer (score 1):

OK, we have the same issue and the only fix I know of is the following:

Add the following entry into the users registry.

> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\Internet]
>   "OpenDocumentsReadWriteWhileBrowsing"=dword:00000001

For a large number of users this would need to be done via Group Policy of course.

Comment: I will look in to thisn, and mark as answer if so.

Comment: Was this an answer, Frederik?